# Do Web Push Notifications work in an Apache Cordova Android app?

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, web-push

I'm working on a *progressive web app* (PWA) that will also get embedded into an Android app with Apache Cordova. Will [**Web Push** Notifications](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/a) work for an Apache Cordovo Android app like **native push** notfications or do I need to use a plugin for that?

Comment: ever got it working Tom?

Comment: @Franz-RobertvanVugt No :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**PWA** will be just a **SPA** which will render on *web-view* and *Cordova* will provide the bridging between *native* and *PWA*.

**Now the point, is Cordova support PWA?**

In general, *Cordova* has little to do with *PWAs*. Yes, there is a ***Cordova* *browser platform*** . But that does not matter much, because very few plugins support it. You need to check the docs of each plugin you are using, to see if they support the ***browser platform***.

As far as your requirement looks you can use use [**phonegap-plugin-push**](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/API.md#browser) which also support ***browser platform***.

**Reference:**

**1.** https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PLATFORM_SUPPORT.md

**2.** https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-roadmap/issues/180

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add an update to this question. As of 2021, Phonegap is no longer maintained and has been discontinued by Apache.

[On their website](https://phonegap.com/)

> Adobe has discontinued PhoneGap Build and ended investment in PhoneGap
> and Apache Cordova.

On August 2020 Apache wrote this article on their [blog](https://blog.phonegap.com/update-for-customers-using-phonegap-and-phonegap-build-cc701c77502c)

> In the context of these developments and declining PhoneGap usage,
> Adobe is focusing on providing a platform that enables developers to
> build, extend, customize and integrate with Adobe products. Today, we
> are announcing the end of development for PhoneGap and PhoneGap Build
> and the end of our investment in Apache Cordova. The PhoneGap Build
> service will be discontinued on October 1, 2020.

If you are developing a PWA or  Hybrid app, you are better off utilizing [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/) or BEST case scenario the [Cordova Cli](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/). Phonegap and any phonegap components and/or plugins should not be a solution of choice if you want to avoid smashing your head up against a wall further down the line.

### New solutions (2021)

1. Ionic Framework with Push Notifications

- https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/

2. Cordova Cli Push Plugin

- https://github.com/havesource/cordova-plugin-push